# Do Android TV devices support subtitle styles?

Tags: chromecast, google-cast, android-tv

I have a Chromecast app for Android which apparently also works on a Sony Android TV. The user says that my subtitle styles work on his Chromecast but not on his Sony TV.

I use `TextTrackStyle` and `setTextTrackStyle` to set the subtitle style.

Are they supported on Android TV?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: @AliNaddaf I would have but I don't have any Android TV devices, only Chromecast devices. I might buy a Nexus Player but I certainly can't afford to get a Sony TV just for a quick test.

Comment: Nexus player will do fine :)

Comment: @ULazdins but will it behave 100% like the Sony Android TV? and I guess can someone just tell me whether subtitle styles are supported on Android TV so I can answer the user?

Comment: Not sure but I think it will work, it will only depend on the version of android tv and chromecast (or brand specific settings).See Ali's [TextTrackStyle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35530745/android-chromecast-companion-library-set-texttrackstyle-error-2103) and [Chromecast subtitle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951929/chromecast-subtitle) for better understanding regarding the the subtitles/subtitle style. To finalize it, it is way better to test it or check the support of the said tv brand to confirm. Hope it helps!

Comment: Considering the user says my subtitle styles work fine on his Chromecast but not on his Sony TV then my guess is that his tv doesn't support them.